# location.assign() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history

I am having an issue with URLs not being added to the browser history stack. These short piece of code clearly demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Page A</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page A</h1>
    <script>
      location.assign("PageB.html");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Page B</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page B</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Typing the address "localhost/PageA.html" into the browser address bar should place Page A's URL in the browser history. The location.assign("PageB.html") should then place Page B's URL on top of Page A's in the browser history. However, I find this not to be the case. Page A's URL is never placed in the browser history. Why is that? How can I keep Page A's URL in the browser history?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) on `location.assign` your parameter has to be a URL, So you would need the relative path pointing to `PageB.html`.

I'm assuming it should be something like this `/PageB.html` the `/` is very important here. You're telling JavaScript that you are in the current directory relative of the file you are on and then to look for `PageB.html`

Comment: `/` here means go to root, i.e the inverse of your sayings, but actually the same as when there isn't since OP is already in said root directory. + none of these say anything about history...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not even waiting for the document has been closed before redirecting to the next page, this page indeed will not make it to the history.

To fix this, you can simply wait or the DOMContentLoaded event and add a zero timeout. This will ensure the document will have been closed and the history entry registered:

```js
const pageB_html = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob( [ `
  <DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head> <title>Page B</title> </head>
    <body>
      <br>
      <h1>Page B</h1>
      <button id="btn">history.back()</button>
      <script>
        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = e =>
          history.back();
      <\/script>
    </bod>
  </html>`
  ], { type: 'text/html' } )
);
addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setTimeout( _ =>location.assign( pageB_html ) );
} );
```

```css
:root{ color: red }
```

```html
<h1>Page A</h1>
```

But note that having a page redirecting directly makes for very bad UX in my opinion. In your position I would reconsider the need for this.

Comment: OK. It does appear to be a timing issue with the complete loading of PageA.html. I used the jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){location.assign("PageB.html");});` to force the `location.assign()` until after the page fully loads and this worked. However, the purpose of the `location.assign()` was to short circuit the page loading process.

From the small snippet of example code I provided I do not see where you can make the determination that this "makes for very bad UX"; as I did not provided the context in which it is used. Please don't jump to conclusions with your "opinion".

Comment: This snippet is enough to see that your users will perform an action that should direct them to *pageA*, but instead they'll end on *pageB* and as if it wasn't enough, you will block them in an history loop... Please let me express my concerns about what my experience identifies as a not thoroughly thought design.

Comment: As I stated, this is only an example. A snippet of code to illustrate an issue, not the actual code where the issue is being observed.

Comment: And even though you did ask the question, this Q/A is not only for you. You did reconsider the need for it, you dimmed it was good enough, good. Future readers will also need to reconsider it for their case.